# MailChimp send the same email multiple times

Tags: mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

Is it possible to send the same email multiple times?

I tried via API to add email to queue, but I cannot remove it anyway. And if I don't, I get message "You've already sent this email to the subscriber." [There was answer in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44562589/mailchimp-automation-send-same-email-multiple-time). However, I need to be able to send email many (not constant) times, thus creating N amount of campaigns does not work for me. Therefore, the only option was to remove subscriber from list and add it back again, however, also doing this did not trigger the email to be sent.

Am I out of luck with MailChimp, is there a way or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing rigth, it is one of mailchimp 'smart' restrictions, like 'no more than 255 symbols in merge field'. You can workaround it, just create new campaign with one email.

I post example below, replace placeholders with rigth values. You can find TEMPLATE_ID in browser address bar when you edit template. (templates/design?tid=TEMPLATE_ID)

```
POST https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns

{
  "type" : "regular",
  "recipients" : {
    "list_id" : "${LIST_ID}",
    "segment_text" : "${SUBJECT}",
    "segment_opts" : {
      "match" : "all",
      "conditions" : [ {
        "condition_type" : "TextMerge",
        "op" : "is",
        "field" : "EMAIL",
        "value" : "${USER_EMAIL}"
      } ]
    }
  },
  "settings" : {
    "subject_line" : "${SUBJECT}",
    "title" : "${SUBJECT}",
    "from_name" : "${YOUR_COMPANY}",
    "reply_to" : "${YOUR_COMPANY_EMAIL}",
    "to_name" : "*|FNAME|* *|LNAME|*",
    "template_id" : ${TEMPLATE_ID}
  }
}
```

after creating, check subscriber count ( should be "recipient_count":1), save campaign id and start campaign.

```
POST https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns/${CAMPAIGN_ID}/actions/send
```

after that, wait some time, no less than 1 min, and delete campaign with

```
DELETE https://usX.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/campaigns/${CAMPAIGN_ID}
```

Comment: Thanks! I kind of felt that it might be that way, thus we ended up using Mandrill, which was an easier solution that this workaround.